# The filter in the filter

Tags: jquery

I want write the filter in the filter. I recive from "Spring" on UI this code:

```
<div th:each="curtain : ${allCurtain}">
                <div class="color" th:classappend="${curtain.color} +' '+ ${curtain.paint}">

                <div class="pic" id="mainDiv">
```

Filters menu has such appearance:

```
     <div class="searchColor" id="filterColor">
                <div class="searchTextColor"> Color: </div>

                <input type="checkbox" name="rbn" id="white"  value="white" />white
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="rbn" id="beige"   value="beige"/>beige
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="rbn" id="cream"   value="cream"/>cream
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="rbn" id="gold"  value="gold"/>gold
                <br/>
              </div>
 <div class="searchColor" id="searchPaint">
                <div class="searchTextColor"> Paint:</div>
                <input type="radio" name="paintRbn" id="abstract"  value="abstract" />abstract
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" name="paintRbn" id="geometrical"  value="geometrical"/>geometrical
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" name="paintRbn" id="classical" value="classical"/>classical
                <br/>
 </div
```

> I want to make: When I select color checkbox, I recive filter from color. I recive many curtains only selected color. After that I can select paint checkbox and this filter will be seeking in recived curtains. I wrote this code:

```
  $(function() {

    var firstRun = true;
    $('input').change(function() {
        var category = $(this).val();

        if (firstRun==true) {
            $('.color').hide();
            firstRun = false;
        }
        if($('#filterColor input:checked') !=0) {

            this.checked ? $('.' + category).show() : $('.' + category).hide();
         if ($('#searchPaint input:checked') !=0){
                this.checked ? $('.' + category).show() : $('.' + category).hide();
            }
        }

        if ($('#filterColor input:checked').length == 0 && $('#searchPaint input:checked').length == 0) {
            $('.color').show();
            firstRun = true;
        }
    });
});
```

But this code seek on all web-page not in color filter.
Can you help me to understand how to make a working code?